# Combine a sparkline into gauge

Tags: reporting-services, charts, gauge, sparklines

See this image of my gauge:

[image: http://i1365.photobucket.com/albums/r745/twarden11/gauge_zpseee35663.jpg]

I need to convert the Savings Goal bar into a line (Sparkline) that cut across the other 4 measurements. Will SSRS allow me to do that? Or is there another way to do it that I just don't know about? I've tried manipulating the properties of the Savings Goal bar to force it to go across the gauge using width and height, but without success. It might work, but I'm fairly new to SSRS, so I may just be missing something.

Comment: ANSWER: Of course as soon as I resort to posting the question, I figure out the answer. I changed my pointer in my gauge from a Bar to a Marker, adjusted the width and height, and that did the trick. Now I just have to figure out how to bring the horizontal bar to be in front of the vertical bars, but I'm sure I can figure it out.

Comment: (I would have answered in the answer section, but I have to wait 8 hours to do so because I don't have enough points)